# jQuery content to load first

Tags: jquery

I have a div:

Content

I made a jQuery that will change the name of the url into something with hash ... etc. My problem is when I go on a page example.com/#/page-1 it first loads the content from .content for some miliseconds then it changes to my content. 
How can I make the content to load first? I have to empty the .content before it loads or something?

Thanks.

```
$(function() {

    var $mainContent = $('.content'),
        siteUrl = "http://" + top.location.host.toString(),
        $internalLinks = $('a[href^="' + siteUrl + '"]'),
        hash = window.location.hash,
        URL = '',
        $el;

    if (hash) {
        hash = hash.substring(1);
        URL = hash + '#inside';
        $mainContent.load(URL);
    };

    $internalLinks.each(function(){
        $(this).attr("href", "#" + this.pathname);
    }).click(function(){
        load_posts();
        $el = $(this);
        URL = $el.attr("href").substring(1);
        URL = URL + '#inside';

    });

});
```

Comment: "it first loads the content from .content for some miliseconds then it changes to my content" .. didn't get this  ??

Comment: I'm a bit confused here. Do you have HTML in the element with the class "content" already? Because that's going to show up until this JavaScript is run when the document finishes loading. If you don't want it to show, hide it using `.hide()`.

Comment: Inside .content div I have some text 'Text'
When I go into the example.com/#/page1 it first loads the 'Text' for some miliseconds then it replaces the content to the current page. Probablty the content loads first and then the script from footer it changes it to the correct one.

Comment: Mike McCaughan , yes I have HTML content

Answer (score 0):

Well as Mike already say here the best way is to hide all body section in your html by default.

```
<body style="display:none;">
```

And then at the end of your script add this line:

```
$('Body').show();
```

But be carefull. This could lead to problem that people with javascript turned off will assume the site just crashed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok ... I solved my problem using this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $('.content').empty();
});
```

There was a problem with my code. When I was loading the content into .content I had inside wordpress stuff like  and  so I couldn'y hide it like you guys said because it repeated the same thing over and over again. Your answers were right. Thank you.